# python asyncio non blocking performance in websockets send and receive

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I want to increase performance to send msg without blocking the reception. I want to use dead I/O time between sends of task1 and task2 to concurrently receive msg.

The question is if the main loop is non blocking and if test_speed2 is more performance that test_speed1 or if you have a different approach.

Thanks in advance

```
async def test_speed1():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(ws.send(msg1))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(ws.send(msg2))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    await task1
    await task2
```

or

```
async def test_speed2():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(ws.send(msg1))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(ws.send(msg2))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

main tasks

```
async def connection():
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            await ws.recv()
```

```
async def checkSignal():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        if signal:
            test_speed1()
```

main loop

```
async def runapp():
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(connection())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(checkSignal())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
    await task3
    await task4

        
def main(argv):
    asyncio.run(runapp())
```